# Do weak references in objective c get randomly deallocated?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the example below, I've defined abc to be a weak reference.

```
@interface myClass : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, weak) Line *abc

@end

- (id)init
{
    abc = [[Line alloc] init]
}
```

Can abc get deallocated randomly since no one strongly points to it? I'm struggling to understand how things get deallocated in languages like objective c. Since there is no garbage collector, what exactly removes it from memory(by simply setting it to nil and called dealloc?)?

The way I imagine it working is when myClass gets set to nil, it will call dealloc on all of the instance variables that have a reference count of 0. Until myClass gets set to nil, abc will always be in memory. Am I correct?

Comment: abc will be release right after init function returns.. because no one holding the pointer any more... and I don't know where to start but you need to find about difference between "weak" and "strong" in objective c..

Comment: a weak reference will not increase the retain count of an item. so if you end a function or so with a zero retain count (or before sometimes) the object will be deallocated. Or leastways you cannot count on it not being removed.

Comment: You are not correct with that last sentence at least not exactly. Your class will not call dealloc on any object. It will release the objects, declaring that it no longer owns/needs them. Once those objects are not owned by anyone else, they will get dealloc'ed.

Comment: Not randomly. This is very well defined, as @andykkt mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

A `weak` reference is a reference to an object that does not stop it from being deallocated.

In other words, it does not create an owner relationship. Whereas previously you would do this:

In ARC you use weak to ensure you do not own the object it points to.

Read more information [here](http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/)

Comment: `weak` does not mean the object can be destroyed at any time. `weak` means the object's retain count isn't increased by the reference. Weak or not, an object is only deallocated when the object's retain count becomes zero.

Comment: it does not create an owner relationship. so don't worry about it.

Comment: In ARC you use weak to ensure you do not own the object it points to.